# AVAssetWriter Error Code cannot create file

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, avcapturesession, avassetwriter, nsdocumentdirectory

My friend is getting this error on his device after assetwriter is created-

Log: AVAssetWriter: 0x1e051900, outputURL = file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/625EA2D8-0B32-41D3-ADFE-64EA5CF47CCE/Documents/AppData/Temp/12-07-13%2011:30:07.mp4, outputFileType = com.apple.quicktime-movie

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-3000 "Cannot create file" UserInfo=0x1e055d30 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e056470 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12149.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot create file}

However i am not getting such error on my device,I am trying to create a movie using assetwriter.I am using iPhone 4s and error is on iPhone 5
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any reason that this code will work on one device while it won't on another.
I believe you cannot create a file name which has a ':' character.
Fix this wherever you create your NSURL and you should be good to go.